# Track Goals Google Analytics across multiple domains and subdomains

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I would like to be able to track conversions across different domains and/or subdomains. Specifically I would like to track where the user who converts, came from.

Use case: User lands on xyz.com after clicking a Facebook or Google ad. User decides to buy and and goes to store.xyz.com. User completes purchase.

I currently have separate analytics setup for the domain and subdomain. What I want to do is track where the user originated from on the subdomains analytics. Is there an easy way to do this? Is there some kind of code I can add to the URL for the "Buy Now" button which takes a user from the domain to the subdomain that would share this info.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, you should be able to use UTM parameters using the [URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en). For Google Ads, well, you get that information when using Google Ads.

As far as the cross-domain tracking goes, you should be able to add [_setDomainName](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName) to your base Google Analytics tracking code.

So, for example, on both your xyz.com and store.xyz.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xyz.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```